# Foreground or Background service to track user's location?

Tags: android, geolocation, tracking, background-foreground

I'm developing a location aware app. This app will start tracking users when they are in their workday. These are the requirements:

1. The service should  run on a regular basis (every 30 or 45 min).
2. It won't matter if the service does not trigger at the same basis everytime.
3. The service needs to upload data to our firestore db.
4. I doesn't need to be triggered on specific conditions (data is on, phone is charging, etc...)
5. I need this to run even if the user restarts his phone.
6. We may need to track the distance traveled by the user. (This is not a requirement per se, but it may be a feature someday)

I know there are a lot of ways to achieve this, but I have not decided which is the option that best fits my scenario. This is what I've thought so far:

- Foreground service combined with BroadcastReciever in case the phone is rebooted
- Background service using the new jetpack's [Workmanager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

Which will the best solution? Do you think there is a better solution than those?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Was thinking create a GPS location tracker so when they are in work premise as well as outside it kinda shows.
Then consider adding the number 5 of the above. Like you said there could be mire awesome solutions than these so lets wait for options.

Comment: looks like you're new here. Only post relevant content in the answer section which provides a solution to the respective question asked. Please use the comment section to get any clarification on the nature of the question.